# I've select element inside a div which is inside a table and that all inside a form when i'm submitting a form i'm not able to get that on my servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is my first ever question after using this site for a long time so content may not be arranged properly. 
                     The main issue I'm Facing is that when i submit this form I'm not able to get the value of select element in side div with ID 'policeName' I'm Getting its values through ajax onchange event of my another select box. I'm able to get value of other select element with name 'station'. What could be wrong here. Please ask if you need some other information.

```
  <tbody>
                                        <tr class="text-center">
                                    <form id="Form<%=i%>" action="../ComplaintAssign" method="get">
                                            <td><input name="index" value="<%=i%>" type="hidden" />
                                                <%=i%></td>
                                            <td><%=bean.getCitizen_id()%></td>
                                            <td><%=bean.getComplaint_id()%></td>
                                            <td><%=sdf.format(bean.getComplaint_date())%></td>
                                            <td><%=bean.getComplaint_against()%> <input type="hidden"
                                                name="fname<%=i%>" id="city"
                                                value="<%=bean.getIncident_city()%>" /></td>
                                            <td><%=bean.getComplaint_sub()%></td>
                                            <td><%=bean.getIncident_city()%></td>
                                            <td><%=bean.getIncident_area()%></td>

                                            <%
                                                Dao da = new Dao();
                                                    List<String> pls = da.getPStation(bean.getIncident_city());
                                            %>

                                            <td>
                                            <div>
                                            <select name="station<%=i%>" onchange="pName(this.value,<%=i%>);">
                                                    <option value="">select Police Station</option>
                                                    <%
                                                        for (Object o : pls) {
                                                    %>
                                                    <option value="<%=o%>"><%=o%></option>
                                                    <%
                                                        }
                                                    %>
                                            </select>
                                            </div>
                                            </td>

                                            <td>
                                                    <div id="policeName<%=i%>">
                                            <select name="police<%=i%>">
                                                    <option value="">Select Police</option>
                                            </select>
                                                    </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><input type="button" name="btn" value="Assign"
                                                onclick="getAssign(<%=i%>);" /></td>
                                    </form>
                                        </tr>
                                </tbody>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because I might be wrong. But I blieved the value should be null on the server side.

Comment: may be but I'm not getting the field itself on server side. Means not getting a name-pair value even if i use get method.

Comment: If your complete is submitted correctly you should get the field; you can check it using either debugger or printint the value on console or log. If you are still struggling just post your servlet code reading the values. I or anyone else might see if there something you don't see.

Comment: Thanks @ujulu for the help but submit form was not working out, but I managed it with ajax post request.